# JavaScript validation and cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, cookies

I am currently in a JavaScript class and my last assignment was to write a code that validates a reservation request form and created cookies. I got half credit on the assignment because my code did not work 100% correctly, which I knew was the case. What happens in the code is when I refresh the page without putting information into the textbox, it yells at me saying "this information is required", but when I fill out some required information and leave the rest of it blank, it still goes to the "thank you for your request" page.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;   
$(":text, #arrival_date, #nights, #name, #email, #phone").after("<span class='error'>*</span>");
$("#reservation_form").submit(
    function(event) {
        var isValid = true;
            $("#arrival_date").focus();
        // validate the requested arrival date
            if ($("#arrival_date").val() == "") {
                $("#arrival_date").next().text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false;
            } 
            else {
                //                       store arrival date in cookie   wds 7/13/2013
                setCookie("guestdate",$("#arrival_date").val(),365);
                $("#arrival_date").next().text(""); 
            }
            // validate the requested arrival nights
            if ($("#nights").val() == "") {
                $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false;
            } 
            else {
                setCookie("guestnights",$("#nights").val(),365);
                $("#nights").next().text(""); 
            }
            // validate the requested name
            if ($("#name").val() == "") {
                $("#name").next().text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false;
            }
            else {
                setCookie("guestname",$("#name").val(),365);
                $("#name").next().text("");
            }
            // validate the requested email
            if ($("#email").val() == "") {
                $("#email").next().text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false;
            }
            else {
                setCookie("guestemail",$("#email").val(),365);
                $("#email").next().text("");
            }
            // validate the requested phone number
            if ($("#phone").val() == "") {
                $("#phone").next().text("This field is required.");
                isValid = false;
            }
            else {
                setCookie("guestphone",$("#phone").val(),365);
                $("#phone").next().text("");
            }
            if (isValid == false) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            }
    } // end function
); // end submit
}); // end ready
```

My professor never told me what I did wrong, and I have another upcoming assignment next week that is very similar to this. All she said in my feedback was "I see validation code but when I run the program none of it works". She doesn't post the answers after the assignment either, which is frustrating. Any assistance would be fantastic!

Comment: I can also post the assignment that shows details if that helps too.

Comment: Can you try setting this up in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hope I did it right!: https://jsfiddle.net/xjr3ro6k/

Comment: You are using jquery validate plugin But i do not see it being properly implemented in your fiddle. See this documentation of the jquery validate plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ I guess you are then setting cookie if valid input.

Comment: So, when I put the validate in and click the submit button even if all information is not filled in, the page won't go to the "thank you for your reservation" form or whatever?

Comment: yes it should not Try once.

Comment: Alright, I added the $("#reservation_form").validate(); before the end function. And it's still not working....am I supposed to put it somewhere else?

Comment: You will need to add rules see source of this example http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this updated fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/xjr3ro6k/4/
When using jquery validate plugin you can pass rules to the form selector validate method like below:

```
$( "#reservation_form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

or you can simply add required in that specific tag and run validate method to the form selector like in this example http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/
You can go through those demos and learn more about this plugin.

keep learning.

Comment: Thank you! After reading the site you provided and looking back at my textbook I see where I went wrong.